# Elastic get documents with min/max and last value

Tags: elasticsearch

Let's say I have an elastic index with the following data:

```
{"var1": 14, "time": "2019-02-12T13:01:00.000Z"}
{"var2": 1423, "time": "2019-02-12T13:01:02.000Z"}
{"var3": 114, "time": "2019-02-12T13:01:03.000Z"}
{"var2": 214, "time": "2019-02-12T13:01:04.000Z"}
{"var3": 414, "time": "2019-02-12T13:01:05.000Z"}
{"var1": 124, "time": "2019-02-12T13:01:06.000Z"}
{"var2": 914, "time": "2019-02-12T13:01:07.000Z"}
{"var3": 8614, "time": "2019-02-12T13:01:06.000Z"}
{"var2": 74, "time": "2019-02-12T13:01:07.000Z"}
{"var3": 174, "time": "2019-02-12T13:01:08.000Z"}
{"var4": 144, "time": "2019-02-12T13:01:09.000Z"}
{"var4": 714, "time": "2019-02-12T13:01:10.000Z"}
{"var4": 813, "time": "2019-02-12T13:01:11.000Z"}
{"var2": 65, "time": "2019-02-12T13:01:12.000Z"}
{"var1": 321, "time": "2019-02-12T13:01:13.000Z"}
```

I would like to write ONE query that can retrieve the minimum of a variable, the maximum of a variable and the last n values of a variable in a given time interval.
It is important that I need the actual document that has the min or the max or the last value (this is why I'm using top_hits for the min and max instead of the min or max aggregations).

So far I have this query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "time": {
              "gte": "2019-02-12T13:01:00.000Z",
              "lt": "2019-02-12T13:01:15.000Z"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "max_var1": {
      "top_hits": {
        "size": 1,
        "sort": [{
          "var1": {"order": "desc"}
        }]
      }
    },
    "min_var2": {
      "top_hits": {
        "size": 1,
        "sort": [{
          "var2": {"order": "asc"}
        }]
      }
    },
    "last_var4": {
      "top_hits": {
        "size": 3,
        "sort": [{
          "time": {"order": "desc"}
        }],
        "_source": ["var4"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The query returns correctly the min and the max value but it doesn't return the correct last 3 value for `var4`, because it takes the last from all the documents in the given time interval, and not the documents that have `var4` in it.
So the question is how to get the last n documents for a given variable inside this query.

I know I could use the multi search API to execute several queries at once, but I would like to know if it is possible to have it in one query.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filtered aggregation to the rescue. Simply make sure to constrain the `last_var4` aggregation to only those docs that actually have the field `var4`.

```
{
    ...
    "last_var4": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "filter": {
            "exists": {
              "field": "var4"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "last_var4": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 3,
            "sort": [
              {
                "time": {
                  "order": "desc"
                }
              }
            ],
            "_source": [
              "var4"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, works as expected. Thank you very much.